# Extract function to separate file in C#

Tags: c#

There is a too long file which I want to optimize through extracting parts into separate files. In JS/TS we can write this:

- file1:

  ```
  export var test = () => ... // do stuff
  ```
- file2:

  ```
  import (or require) file1
  file1.test();
  ```

--> (How) is this possible in C#? (Without the use of classes)

When I try to write the code into a separate file, I get this error:

```
 namespace MyFavoriteNamespace;
 var test = () => ... // do stuff

The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code
```

Sorry, I feel like being a total noob here.

Comment: There isn't really a mechanism in C# to do something like that. [Partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) are the closest, but are, well, classes. This sounds like an X/Y problem though, what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: What's wrong with classes?

Comment: C# is an object oriented programming language, you can do nothing without the use of classes.

Comment: @shingo "nothing" isn't quite right, now that top-level implicit entry-points exist; "almost nothing": sure!

Comment: @vc74 in my view, classes sometimes are boilerplate, nothing wrong, I just like to keep things simple if they don't have to be complex. you'd need to wrap one method in a class and new up. in JS you can just import and call it. just personal preference when looking at maintainability.

Comment: If you consider classes as boilerplate why using an object oriented language in the first place? Allowing object orientation and functional programming at the same time like you seem to propose makes the system more complex in my eyes not less.

Comment: @Lennart thanks for your answer, just cleaning up. I know I can use classes, just wondering if there are simpler ways here. I find writing things like Helper.Help() not very astetic :) In PHP for example you also can include/require another file.

Comment: @Ralf great point, of course there is stuff around this simple example that make me use it :)

Comment: Normally it would be best to refactor things into multiple classes, but it's possible to split a large class up over multiple files using [partial classes and methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods). But I see this as an anti-pattern unless it's being used with auto-generated code.

Comment: Thanks guys, I see this question as answered.

Comment: "When I try to write the code into a separate file" - only one of your files in a "Do not use top level statements" style app, may omit the `namespace X{ class Y{ ... } }` text. The compiler writes it for you silently, behind the scenes anyway, so don't worry about having to put it in to every other file you write (just do it)... "In JS/TS we can..." - yea, "do pretty much anything we want" - it's not a benefit

Comment: Your problem is not object orientation, in fact even TS and JS are object oriented. Your problem is the keyword var. C# does not use modules or libraries or whatever you wish to call it that way at all. Please state what exactly you want to accomplish and it is recommended to properly learn a language before asking, in this case wrong, questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to correct one misconception, based on the comment:

> you'd need to wrap one method in a class and **new up**

You don't need `new` if you have static functions. They still need to be part of a class, but they can be called directly.

```
namespace MyStuff;

internal class Helper {
  public static string Help() => "Help text";
}
```

Can be called with without `new`-ing anything.

There are 3 ways to call it, with varying degree of verbosity. The most verbose would be:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(MyStuff.Helper.Help());
```

This can be cleaned up to:

```
using System;
using MyStuff;

Console.WriteLine(Helper.Help());
```

*BUT*, you can make it even closer to what you want with `using static`:

```
using static System.Console;
using static MyStuff.Helper;

WriteLine(Help());
```

Answer (score 0):

A practical way of doing this is using a [partial class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods). You can think of it as one class split into multiple files:

(typing off the to of my head, might not compile and needs tweaks)

In one file you can define a few methods:

```cs
// file: MyClass.foo.cs
partial class MyClass
{
    void Foo()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

...then more in another file:

```cs
// file: MyClass.bar.cs
partial class MyClass
{
    void Bar()
    {
        // do somethingelse
    }
}
```

You can have as many files as you want. Of course this might not be the best design and/or refactoring solution here (it's usually used to extend auto generated code) but it should help with chopping big files into groups of functions.

**Edit**: Oops apologies @Lennart already answered it in comments, just realised! - honest :P